# Multiple CollectionView - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am working on this for 5 hours now and I have changed a lot of code (I am still beginner and this is also way how I learn behavior of swift), but I am stuck now and I really need your help.

I have small app that have 3 buttons, but 2 of them segue to different (separate) CollectionView (Not two collectionView on same page, same view Controller, but on different View Controllers inside storyboard).

[image]

When I have made first CollectionView, everything worked fine, but after I made second, first one still works OK, but second just give me blank black screen (in simulator).

I have tried to fix this on my own by changing a lot of stuff inside code, and I never got any error, I can run app normally in simulator, but always get black screen on second Collection View.

In second CollectionView I have made same as in first one (connected buttons, outlets, ViewControllers with classes I have created), but it doesn't show images in second CollectionView, so probably error for that is somewhere in ViewController.swift and I am looking and changing code for hours now, but no luck, so I am asking you if you could please help.

Hope I didn't messed up to much:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewTrening: UICollectionView!

let imageArray = [UIImage(named: "slika1"),
                  UIImage(named: "slika2"),
                  UIImage(named: "slika3"),
                  UIImage(named: "slika4"),
                  UIImage(named: "slika5"),
                  UIImage(named: "slika6"),
                  UIImage(named: "slika7"),
                  UIImage(named: "slika8"),
                  UIImage(named: "slika9"),
                  UIImage(named: "slika10"),
                  UIImage(named: "slika11"),
                  UIImage(named: "slika12"),
                  UIImage(named: "slika13")]

let vjezbe = ["Zgibovi: 30 sekundi", "Trbušnjaci: 30 sekundi"]

let vjezbeSlike = [UIImage(named: "Vjezba-zgibovi"),
                   UIImage(named: "Vjezba-trbusnjaci")]


override func viewDidLoad()  {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.imageArray.count
}

func collectionViewTrening(collectionViewTrening: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.vjezbeSlike.count
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    cell.imageView?.image = self.imageArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}

func collectionViewTrening(collectionViewTrening: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionViewTrening.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellTrening", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TreningCollectionViewCell

    cell.imageViewTrening?.image = self.vjezbeSlike[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showImage", sender: self)
}

func collectionViewTrening(collectionViewTrening: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showImageTrening", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showImage" {

        let indexPaths = self.collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!
        let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as NSIndexPath
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! NewViewController
        vc.image = self.imageArray[indexPath.row]!

   } else if segue.identifier == "showImageTrening" {
        let indexPaths = self.collectionViewTrening!.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!
        let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as NSIndexPath
        let vc  = segue.destinationViewController as! TreningViewController
        vc.imageTrening = self.vjezbeSlike[indexPath.row]!
    }
}
```

}

Thanks. ;)

Comment: Is the collectionview's datasource set to your view controller? You can check the outlet in IB or set it manually in code: `collectionView.datasource = self`

Comment: Are you using two different ViewControllers in your storyboard? Are there two different collectionViews in your same ViewController?

Comment: Yes, I am using two different ViewControllers in my storyboard for two different collectionViews, but code is in same ViewController.swift - is this bad practice or? I suppose all this code can be wrote simpler for two separate collectionViews, but like I said, I am still beginner and I am learning :) ;)

Comment: @James Bone - yes, I have connect everything. One collectionView works fine, but after I have made first one and test it and when I so that it works, I have made another one, repeat the process, connect everything and repeat code, but second collectionView gives me black screen, not showing any images from array.